# With TFS when other users create folders and check them in, they appear hidden to me when I get latest version

Tags: asp.net, tfs, tfsbuild

We are all working on a solution together using TFS. If user A creates a new folder, and checks in the solution user B will see all those folders as grayed out icons when they pull down the latest version. So when we make a change and check those changes in, the build server builds everything except those folders.

Is the user checking these files in incorrectly, or maybe its a config setting on the TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you didn't got a new version of your VS project file, which is mapping the directories ?

Or, maybe you have unresolved conflicts, that are blocking the last version of the project file.

Comment: How can I view conflicts if they exist? How do I compare my version with other versions?

Comment: You can navigate into the TFS tree and show difference on the .vsproj file, and see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181433(v=vs.100).aspx#resolve_conflicts for conflicts

Comment: It looks like one of the other users did not check in their project file. Thanks cubitouch.

Comment: @user3108526 Got the same problem on my last mission ;)